# Multiple tables in html have the same id selector and one of them needs to be hidden on click

Tags: jquery, html

I have multiple tables with the same id and I want to hide a particular table when it is clicked.
Please suggest me about how to do it.

Comment: add different class names to each of your tables and access them using selectors!

Comment: You are suggesting a bad practice here, ID should be unique not classes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does ID have to be unique in the whole page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page)

Comment: I edited answer,and provided jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use unique ID ,its the best practice,classes are not Unique
classTable=> class given to all tables
And the id for each table is Unique .

```
<script>
$(".classTable").click(function() {

    var tblId=$(this).attr("id");
    alert(tblId);
    $("#"+tblId).hide();
});
</script>
```

on any table User clicks , Get id of the current Table class which is clicked.And hide only those class by taking its ID ,As IDs are unique

Fiddle =>http://jsfiddle.net/c7F7a/

Answer (score 2):

`id` is unique, you need to use class instead, then you can do:

```
$('.classOfYourTables').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```